# Error 1034 when uploading new version of file to wiki ('oldimage' is corrupt)

Tags: mediawiki

I tried to upload a new version of an image file to my wiki and got this error:

```
Error 1034: Index for table 'oldimage' is corrupt; try to repair it (localhost)
```

I am running Mediawiki 1.35.6 on an Ubuntu Mate 22.04 LTS linux box (my private wiki). PHP 8.1.2, and Apache/2.4.52.

I don't know how to do this repair the error suggests.

**UPDATE:** I can `sudo mysqlcheck -c mywiki oldimage` and got the following result:

```
rwp@wiki:/var/lib/mysql/mywiki$ sudo mysqlcheck -c mywiki oldimage
mywiki.oldimage
Warning  : InnoDB: Index 'oi_actor_timestamp' contains 15 entries, should be 12.
Warning  : InnoDB: Index 'oi_name_timestamp' contains 15 entries, should be 12.
Warning  : InnoDB: Index 'oi_name_archive_name' contains 15 entries, should be 1                             2.
Warning  : InnoDB: Index 'oi_sha1' contains 15 entries, should be 12.
error    : Corrupt
```

I don't know what command to issue to repair `oldimage`.

**UPDATE 2:** I did the following from CLI.

```
sudo mysql
show databases;
use mywiki;
repair table mywiki.oldimage use_frm;
```

And result is:

```
MariaDB [mywiki]> repair table mywiki.oldimage use_frm;
+-------------------+--------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Table             | Op     | Msg_type | Msg_text                                                |
+-------------------+--------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| mywiki.oldimage   | repair | note     | The storage engine for the table doesn't support repair |
+-------------------+--------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: are you using MyISAM?  InnoDB is a more durable choice.  You should be able to repair it with https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/repair-table.html

Comment: Thanks @erik258 - I ran `myisamchk` at CLI and it is present. How do I know if I'm using InnoDB?  I ran `myisamchk -c oldimage.ibd` and it says the table is not a MyISAM-table, so i assume in is InnoDB.

Comment: Sounds like it's already innodb.  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31701/finding-and-fixing-innodb-index-corruption

Comment: I ran the repair specified by item 6 [here](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/12/mysqlcheck/), and it came back with `The storage engine for the table doesn't support repair`.

Comment: Ok, I've got it now I think.  I'll post answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the solution I fumbled around onto (thanks to @erik258).

First, I stopped the web server that uses the database.

```
sudo service apache2 stop
```

Then,

```
sudo mysql
show databases;
use mywiki;
repair table mywiki.oldimage use_frm;
```

The repair did not work because the table, being `InnoDB`, did not support a repair.  So, I altered the table to `MyISAM` as per [here](https://www.stellarinfo.com/article/storage-engine-for-the-table-doesnt-support-repair.php) first.  Did the repair, and then converted it back to `InnoDB`.

```
sudo mysql
show databases;
use mywiki;
alter table mywiki.oldimage engine=MyISAM;
repair table mywiki.oldimage use_frm;
```

It reported table **repaired**.  Then I changed it back to `InnoDB` and all working fine now.

```
alter table mywiki.oldimage ENGINE=InnoDB;
quit;
```

Then restarted the web server that uses this database.

```
sudo service apache2 stop
```